# be false vs be_falsey in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I know be false will just return true if the expected value is a pure false value, wherease be_falsey will return true if the expected value is either false or nil.

However, I fail to understand when would I use one or the other. I fail to see an example where be_falsey would be more useful than be false.

Comment: [Consider renaming `be_true` and `be_false` to `be_truthy` and `be_falsey`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/283)

Comment: I take it you've read through [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/283) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of situations in Ruby where you get a `nil` result and want to treat it like `false`. For example, suppose we have a method that handles an options hash, and we want the absence of an option to be the same as the option set to false:

```
def verbose?(opts)
  opts[:verbose]  
end

opts = { verbose: false }
expect(verbose?(opts)).to be_falsey # => PASS

opts = { verbose: true }
expect(verbose?(opts)).to be_falsey # => FAIL

opts = {}
expect(verbose?(opts)).to be_falsey # => PASS
```

Obviously this is a simplistic example (you could argue that `verbose?` should always return `true` or `false`), but similar scenarios are common in Ruby.

Comment: Small style point, though: Boolean methods should return true or false, not nil. So when testing boolean methods (those that end in `?`), use `be(true)` or `be(false)`, not `be_truthy` or `be_falsey`.

Answer (score 0):

One example I can think of is for a unit test for a method. The method would be used in such a way that you are not really interested in the result, but only whether it is truthy/falsey.

Consider a method that checks if there is a record with a given value is in the db:

```
Class Foo
  def self.has_value? value
    Foo.find(value: value)
  end
```

This method would be used as:

```
if Foo.has_value?(value)
   ...
```

Now, you could write a test like this:

```
let(:foo ){ create :foo )
expect(Foo.has_value?(1)).to == foo
```

But this obscures the intent of the method. The method's intent is not to find a foo. It is to tell you whether a foo with a given value exists or not.

To express the intent of the method it might be better to use

```
expect(Foo.has_value(1).to be_truthy
expect(Foo.has_value(2).to be_falsey
```

In Rails, `if model.save` is often used. This is the same pattern.